Hadoop Truncating Strings at 256,512,1024 Characters Arbitrarily
this is my first post so apologies for any confusion. I am attempting to run a DNA sequence analysis through Map Reduce. Here are the important parts of my mapper.sh script:
while read line
do
    echo "[$(date)] **$HOSTNAME** Running megacc_cr with input: $line" >> ${TMP_LOG_FILE}
    
    # Execute megacc_cr and capture the output and exit status
    result=$(./megacc_cr $line --map-reduce-bootstrap)
    status=$?

    # Trim whitespace from the result
    result=$(echo "$result" | xargs)
    # Further cleaning up the spaces,tabs, etc. from the result
    result=$(echo "$result" | tr -d '[:space:]') 
    # Log the trimmed result and status

    

    # Output the trimmed result for Hadoop to process
    if [ -n "$result" ]; then
        echo "$result 1"
    else
        echo "[$(date)] **$HOSTNAME** Empty result detected." >> ${TMP_LOG_FILE}
    fi

(I already checked the whole mapper.sh script in shellcheck.net)
The main point of error is here: result=$(./megacc_cr $line --map-reduce-bootstrap)
$line is just some parameters for the megacc analysis, in this case $line is equal to "-a infer_NJ_nucleotide.mao -d SpiderA.fas" (some parameters irrelevant to the problem).
This whole script executes as many times as the user specifies and each run executes/exemplifies a singular bootstrap analysis. When i run this locally, I get the correct output:
Command:
result=$(./megacc_cr_test -a infer_NJ_nucleotide.mao -d SpiderA.fas --map-reduce-bootstrap:
echo "$result 1" >> output.txt
Output:
(((A_californicus_GMY190,SDSUMY1467_Aliatypus_gulosus),((((Calommata_signata_MY4703,(Atypus_karschi_MY4706,(Sphodros_rufipes_MY032,Sphodros_abboti_MY026))),(((SDSUMY4589_Hexurella,Hexurella_sp_MY1104),((((((calisoga_sp_MY4085,Bymainiella_sp_MY884),Namirea_sp_MY846),euagrus_sp_MY4295),Microhexura_sp_MY4016),Thelechoris_sp_MY050),(Hypochilus_kastoni_G2519,hypochilus_sp_H595))),CJG3438_Mecicobothrium_thorelli)),(SDSUMY4026_Megahexura_fulva,megahexura_sp_MY4378)),(Hexura_picea_MY090,SDSUMY1125_Hexura_rothi))),(SDSUMY0120_Antrodiaetus_apachecus,SDSUMY4700_Antrodiaetus_roretzi),((A_hadros_MY459,SDSUMY0633_Antrodieatus_gertschi),(atypoides_sp_AR17,atypoides_sp_MY1253))); 1

((((A_californicus_GMY190,SDSUMY1467_Aliatypus_gulosus),((((Calommata_signata_MY4703,(Atypus_karschi_MY4706,(Sphodros_rufipes_MY032,Sphodros_abboti_MY026))),(((SDSUMY4589_Hexurella,Hexurella_sp_MY1104),((((((calisoga_sp_MY4085,Bymainiella_sp_MY884),euagrus_sp_MY4295),Namirea_sp_MY846),Microhexura_sp_MY4016),Thelechoris_sp_MY050),(Hypochilus_kastoni_G2519,hypochilus_sp_H595))),CJG3438_Mecicobothrium_thorelli)),(SDSUMY4026_Megahexura_fulva,megahexura_sp_MY4378)),(Hexura_picea_MY090,SDSUMY1125_Hexura_rothi))),(SDSUMY0120_Antrodiaetus_apachecus,SDSUMY4700_Antrodiaetus_roretzi)),(A_hadros_MY459,SDSUMY0633_Antrodieatus_gertschi),(atypoides_sp_AR17,atypoides_sp_MY1253)); 1

(((A_californicus_GMY190,SDSUMY1467_Aliatypus_gulosus),((((Calommata_signata_MY4703,(Atypus_karschi_MY4706,(Sphodros_rufipes_MY032,Sphodros_abboti_MY026))),(((SDSUMY4589_Hexurella,Hexurella_sp_MY1104),((((((calisoga_sp_MY4085,Bymainiella_sp_MY884),Namirea_sp_MY846),euagrus_sp_MY4295),Microhexura_sp_MY4016),Thelechoris_sp_MY050),(Hypochilus_kastoni_G2519,hypochilus_sp_H595))),CJG3438_Mecicobothrium_thorelli)),(SDSUMY4026_Megahexura_fulva,megahexura_sp_MY4378)),(Hexura_picea_MY090,SDSUMY1125_Hexura_rothi))),(SDSUMY0120_Antrodiaetus_apachecus,SDSUMY4700_Antrodiaetus_roretzi),((A_hadros_MY459,SDSUMY0633_Antrodieatus_gertschi),(atypoides_sp_AR17,atypoides_sp_MY1253))); 1

Each string ending in a 1 is one line. These lines are to be processed by reducer.sh as Key/Value pairs. However, when i run this analysis through hadoop, the mapper.sh produces results like:
(((A_californicus_GMY190,SDSUMY1467_Aliatypus_gulosus),((((Calommata_signata_MY4703,(Atypus_karschi_MY4706,(Sphodros_rufipes_MY032,Sphodros_abboti_MY026))),(((SDSUMY4589_Hexurella,Hexurella_sp_MY1104),((((((calisoga_sp_MY4085,Bymainiella_sp_MY884),euagrus_sp_MY4295),Namirea_sp_MY846),Microhexura_sp_MY4016),Thelechoris_sp_MY050),(Hypochilus_kastoni_G2519,hypochilus_sp_H595))),CJG3438_Mecicobothrium_thorelli)),(SDSUMY4026_Megahexura_fulva,megahexura_sp_MY4378)),(Hexura_picea_MY090,SDSUMY1125_Hexura_rothi))),( 1

SDSUMY0120_Antrodiaetus_apachecus,SDSUMY4700_Antrodiaetus_roretzi),((A_hadros_MY459,SDSUMY0633_Antrodieatus_gertschi),(atypoides_sp_AR17,atypoides_sp_MY1253))); 1

(((A_californicus_GMY190,SDSUMY1467_Aliatypus_gulosus),((((Calommata_signata_MY4703,(Atypus_karschi_MY4706,(Sphodros_rufipes_MY032,Sphodros_abboti_MY026))),(((SDSUMY4589_Hexurella,Hexurella_sp_MY1104),((((((calisoga_sp_MY4085,Bymainiella_sp_MY884),euagrus_sp_MY4295),Namirea_sp_MY846),Microhexura_sp_MY4016),Thelechoris_sp_MY050),(Hypochilus_kastoni_G2519,hypochilus_sp_H595))),CJG3438_Mecicobothrium_thorelli)),(SDSUMY4026_Megahexura_fulva,megahexura_sp_MY4378)),(Hexura_picea_MY090,SDSUMY1125_Hexura_rothi))),(SDSUMY0120_Antrodiaetus_apachecus,SDSUMY4700_Antrodiaetus_roretzi),((A_hadros_MY459,SDSUMY0633_Antrodieatus_gertschi),(atypoides_sp_AR17,atypoides_sp_MY1253))); 1

As you can see, in the Hadoop analysis the first line is truncated at 512 characters and the second line is just the rest of the first line, counted as its own key. And the third line is processed correctly. Hypothetically, if i am doing 50 bootstrap replicates in hadoop, about 5-8 of them will be truncated like this, while the others can exceed 512 characters and produce the correct bootstrap output.
My question is, why is this happening when I simply run this analysis through Hadoop while it produces correct output on the local linux machine. There are 5 slave nodes and this error occurs indiscriminately and randomly on all the nodes.
I also tweaked the mapper.sh script to send the result to a file on the respective local machine that the script was executed on, then aggregating those files on the local machine into HDFS to have the reducer analyze, and the same error occurs, so it doesnt seem to be an issue with how hadoop transfers the newick strings.
When i run this analysis with a very big DNA data set, Hadoop indiscriminately truncates the data at 1024 characters instead of 512 characters, but for very small data sets it doesn't seem to bother. For example, it produced the correct output:
((orangutan,sumatran),((homo_sapiens,(chimpanzee,bonobo)),gorilla),gibbon); 1

Please let me know if there's any more info needed, and I appreciate any response!

Welcome on StackOverflow. May I suggest that you take a look at the help center and especially at How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML??

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

I've removed the Hadoop tag since it didn't appear any hadoop commands/scripts were mentioned or shown

Too much to post in a comment ...
Presume this is BASH script, if not please specify.
Always always quote shell variables, otherwise expect the unexpected!
shellcheck myscript
 
Line 1:
while read line do echo "[$(date)] $HOSTNAME Running megacc_cr with input: $line" >> ${TMP_LOG_FILE}
^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this while loop. Fix to allow more checks.
                ^-- SC1010 (warning): Use semicolon or linefeed before 'do' (or quote to make it literal).
 
Line 20:
fi
  ^-- SC1058 (error): Expected 'do'.
  ^-- SC1072 (error): Expected 'do'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

I think the following can be removed
# Trim whitespace from the result
result=$(echo "$result" | xargs)
# Further cleaning up the spaces,tabs, etc. from the result
result=$(echo "$result" | tr -d '[:space:]') 
# Log the trimmed result and status'

and replaced by modifying the initial result assignment to include the removal.
result=$(./megacc_cr $line --map-reduce-bootstrap | tr -d '[:space:]')

As always, test and see
What is this line, looks syntactically incorrect, and at odds with your command line in the script ? , edit/remove or clarify its relevance.
"""
result=$(./megacc_cr_test -a infer_NJ_nucleotide.mao -d SpiderA.fas --map-reduce-bootstrap: echo "$result 1" >> output.txt
"""
You mention hadoop, but nothing directly relating to its use is shown (have I missed something ? )
